# AngularJS Iterate ng-repeat scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create using bootstrap rows of 3 with data from a scope object using ng-repeat. It is looping every three times because of my ng-if. Basically I would like to know if it's possible to do something like `<h4> {{yogurt[$index+1].name}} </h4>`

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="yogurt in yogurts" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-body">
         <h4> {{yogurt.name}} </h4>
         <h6> {{yogurt.ingredients}} </h6>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just miss the **s** and everything should be ok : `{{yogurts[$index+1].name}} </h4>`

You may check if it's not the last too `{{$last ? : '' : yogurts[$index+1].name}} </h4>`